# What should I do when i get this data cyclic error trying to copy files?

Tags: hard-drive, redundancy

I was trying to copy a file from my local hard drive to an external hard drive and i am getting this error.

[image]

**Cannot copy IMG_9212: Data error (cyclic redundancy check).**

Should i be worried about my data or if my hard drive is corrupted?  What is the best course of action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check your Ram.  With a separate (trusted) computer, download a copy of the [ISO for Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com) and burn a CD from it.  Boot your computer to that disc, and allow it to run for a few hours.  Yes, a few hours.  You want it to complete all the tests, more than once.

Why?  You could have a bad stick of Ram which only produces errors when moving large files through it.  I've seen it more than once.  In one particular case a few years back, I myself had a machine with 3x1gb Ram in the box, one stick of which was bad.  Windows installed fine with the Ram, and there were no operational issues.  Only when I attempted to copy some large files did I develop this same exact issue... CRC errors.  One Memtest86 later and I was removing the bad stick.

Could it also be a bad drive?  Sure.  Run Chkdsk on it, if you are using Windows.  With the drive connected, right click on the drive in Computer/My Computer, choose properties, the Tools tab, and run Error Checking.  Make it do everything from that panel.

Answer (score 0):

1. get CrystalDiskInfo to check the health of both of the drives

NB !!! BEFORE entering any chkdsk commands, check if "/f" flag keeps any data or just deletes all nodes to the actual files! -- "/r" will certainly just DELETE ALL FILES under bad sectors!!!

2. run "chkdsk x:" and "chkdsk x: /f"

DO NOT EVER issue the "chkdsk x: /r" command !!!! NEVER !!!!!

3. if the "/f" flag gives you bad results(sectors), then clone the whole disk to a brand new disk with **ddrescue** (and get more info with Spinrite if needed)
4. it might also be just bad quality cables (inner and outer)
5. NB!!! if Windows also suggests you to format the whole disk just to "initialize" it, then DO NOT ACCEPT IT !
   it is actually a 'good' sign if windows cant find any partitions, because then it atleast means that the disk is working
6. so basically - if you even want to save yourself from any extra hassle, then just use **ddrescue**!

Comment: I'd argue once health has been examined, ddrescue would next best step. Chkdsk for example does not check/verify file's content while most likely it's where the CRC error occurs.